# Probability of spherical particles touching one another in a cylindrical column

Tags: probability, volume

I was wondering if you could help me out with a little problem, as my research is getting rather time restricted at the moment, and due to my limited mathematical background, any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it was just to point me in the right direction.

I have an experiment that involves diluting a solid (S1) in another solid (S2), where particles of S1 cannot be touching one another, in a cylindrical column. It is assumed that the particles of S1 and S2 are spherical in shape and all of the same diameter. The cylindrical column in which they will be packed has a diameter of 12.58 mm, and a length/height of 9.86 mm. The particles, let's say, are all 7.0 um in diameter.

I believe that I have calculated a way to dilute the solid: 24% of S1 with 76% of S2. I will then mix these two using a reciprocal shaker before packing inside the column. However...

... How can I calculate the probability that a particle of S1 will be touching another S1 particle in the column? It would be nice to say that the if I put the S1 and S2 particles in my column as above, there is a ?% chance that an S1 particle will be touching another S1 particle (hopefully, this number will be low).

I hope I have made my question clear. If not, I am happy to expand further, and any help would be very much appreciated (even if it's just pointing me to a theorem that I should consider, etc.).

Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: So, you're mixing two "dusts" so to speak, and then want to know the probability of two S1 particles touching when you pack them together? Just for my sake...is the efficiency of your process dependent on having S1 particles isoloated from each other>?

Comment: Thank you for your response :) Yes, it is; in an ideal world, the S1 particles wouldn't be touching and would be completely isolated from one another. However, I know that that's not possible to do, and so I'd like to be able to assign some number that quantifies this issue. so if I was to randomly pack the two different particles, what is the probability that an S1 particle would touch another S1 particle, for example.I just wonder if this is possible to do or if I'm even going about this question in the wrong manner...

Comment: It sounds doable...there are several frameworks that might work. I'll give it some thought and get back to you.

Comment: BTW: can we assume the particles are the same diameter and are spherical? I need to estimate the packing coordination number.

Comment: Yep! Thanks *:)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I've come up with a useful probability model that is not too complicated.

**Objective**

Estimate the fraction of $S_1$ particles that are touching other $S_1$ particles. Assuming some mixture of two particle types $S_1,S_2$.

---

**Modelling Assumptions**

1. *Packed media is homogenous and infinite in extent.* Requires that the number of particles that touch the edge of the cylinder is much less than the number that are on the interior of the packed material.
2. *S1 and S2 particles are spheres with identical radii*
3. *There are no attractions between particles*

---

**Model Formulation**

*Definitions*

1. $V$ is an arbitrary volume of packed media and $N_1,N_2$ be the number of $S_1,S_2$ particles in that volume, respectively. Let $N=N_1+N_2$ and $f=\frac{N_1}{N}$.
2. $\tau_{N}$ is the fraction of $S_1$ particles in $V$ that are touching another $S_1$ particle
3. $P_N$ is the number of touching pairs of particles in the packed media
4. $X(\omega_i)$ is a random variable that indicates the particle type for the $i^{th}$ particle ($\omega_i$) in $V$. Specifically, $X(\omega_i)=1$ if $\omega_i=S_1$ and is zero otherwise. I will use the shorthand notation $ X(\omega_i)\equiv  X_i$

*Derivations*

The assumption of homogeneity implies that the $X_i$ are independent of one another and $P(X_i=1)=f$. Therefore, $P(X_i=1 \cap X_j = 1)=f^2, \;\; \forall i\neq j$. However, we don't care about the probability that *any* two particles will be $S_1$, we want to know the probability that any two *touching* particles are both $S_1$, assuming an arbitrary packing of identically sized spheres in 3-dimensions.

It turns out that the above situation has been studied in quite a bit of detail. Specifically, I will rely on the Karoly's [Touching Pairs Theorem 1(i)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.5756v1.pdf) to determine the number of touching pairs of particles. I will denote such a pair using indexed sets $\phi_k=\{\omega_i,\omega_j\}$, since the ordering of the particles in the pair is irrelevant and designates the same pairing.

Using our notation, the theorem states:

$$P_N<6N-0.926N^{2/3}$$

Therefore, we have a collection of $P_N$ pair sets $\{\phi_k:k \in \{1...P_N\}\}$

The assumption of homogeneity again implies that the composition of the pairs are independent of one another. However, we run the risk of double-counting the number of particles involved in the pairs, since some pairs may share a common particle.

To address this, I will calculate the *average coordination number* ($C_N$) and use it to calculate the correct number of unique particles among the parings.

$$C_N = 2\frac{P_N}{N}$$

For example, if we were dealing with a gas with weak interactions, then we may have every particle only being linked to one other particle. In this case, $P_N=\frac{1}{2}$ hence the average coordination number is $1$.

Therefore, we can think of each particle as being the center of a cluster with $C_N$ branches (rounding $C_N$ to nearest integer). The number of $(S_1,S_1)$ pairings  in the cluster with center particle being $\omega_i$ is given by $K_i$.

The expected value is calculated conditionally:

- $E[K_i|\omega_i=S_1] = C_Nf$ and
- $E[K_i|\omega_i=S_2] = 0$

Hence, $E[K_i]=P(\omega_i=S_1)E[K_i|\omega_i=S_1] = C_Nf^2$ and the number of $S_1$ particles paired with other $S_1$ particles is expected to be $NC_Nf^2$.

We now have what we need to get our estimate of what fraction of the $S_1$ particles are paired with other $S_1$ particles.

---

**Main Results**

$\tau_{N} < \frac{NC_Nf^2}{N_2} = \frac{f^22P_N}{N_2}=\frac{f^22P_N}{fN}=\frac{2fP_N}{N}=\frac{2f(6N-0.926N^{2/3})}{N}=2f\left(6-0.926N^{-1/3}\right)$

(Note that the coordination number of perfectly packed spheres is 12, so arbitrary packing of finite size are expected to generate less than optimal numbers of pairings)

What we want is $\tau_{\infty}$:

$\tau_{\infty} = \lim\limits_{N\to \infty} \tau_N < 12f$

---

**Discussion**

Essentially, an infinite and homogenous media of two types of spherical particles can only be bounded by the number of pairings for a perfectly packed media.

The derivation for the bound on $\tau_{\infty}$ implies that, *at most*, $12f\times 100\%$ percent of the $S_1$ particles are touching other particles.

Unfortunately, this bound is somewhat conservative, as it implies your mixture is not sufficiently diluted to guarantee anything less than 100% of the $S_2$ particles are paired (which is obviously false...but to what extent is it false?). You will need much more dilution.Therefore,  if we want to get $\tau_{\infty} < D$ then we need $f<\frac{D}{12}$!

In your case, if we want a very low pairing probability (say $D<.01$), then $S_1$ can only be $0.08\%$ of the mixture, for a dilution ratio of 1,250:1! Your apparatus may get quite  big (or conversely the effectiveness will be limited) by such a large bulk dilution ratio requirement.

Comment: Hello again

Thank you very much for taking the time to help me. I just have a few additional questions, if you don't mind?

I've tried to input some of my own values in to come up with some actual numbers. As I know that the height of my cylindrical column is 9.86mm, and the diameter 12.58mm, the volume is 12.26mm^3. The particle size is 7.0 um. Based on that, I calculated the no. of particles that can fit width-ways and length-ways, then multiplied that to obtain how many can fit in total, being 2532763.095 particles.

So, I said that I was going to use 24% of S1 (N1) particles,

Comment: thus f = N1/N = 0.24. I also calculated P_N, which is 15179372.8, and the average coordination number came out as 11.99.

To calculate the % of S1 particles touching other S1 particles, I multiplied f (0.24) by 12 and then 100, to obtain 288%.

So, in your discussion, you're saying that this is a fine number to accept, because this 288% value implies that not only is each particle touching another particle, they're touching more than one other particle, is that correct?

Comment: And so I simply have to play around with that % value to obtain the % that I'm happy with? I.e. if I use 0.08% S1 particles, then only 0.96% will be touching other S1 particles?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: @PastryNinja an $f=24\%$ implies that its possible that ALL of your particles $S_1$ particles are touching at least one other $S_1$ particle, which I don't think is a good result for you. You are trying to ensure that the probability of two $S_1$ particles touching is very low, hence you'll need to adjust $f$ until $\tau_{\infty}$ is bounded by something acceptable to you. If having **at most** 1% touching is fine, then a 0.08% S_1 mixture will definitely do the trick

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it :) When I get enough "reputation" I'll up one your answer! Really very appreciate the effort and help you've given me :) Thank you!

Comment: @PastryNinja can you accept? Or do you need rep for that too?

Comment: All done! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @user76844 may I have some contact and affiliation information from you so I can credit you with this work in my thesis? Thank you :)

Comment: Is it possible to obtain user information for Eupraxis1981/user76844... if some of this work is to be published or put in my thesis, I'd like to credit him. Please get in touch with me...